# How can I show $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n\cos nx\sin nx=0$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I was solving a problem and couldn't get rid of the following term(which didn't appear in the answer), $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} n\cos nx\sin nx$, and Wolfram tells me it actually vanishes for any $x\in\mathbb{C}$.

I can see that by Liouville's theorem, I only need to show this is a bounded function but I'm not so sure how that can be done. Can anyone help me?

Comment: $2\cos nx\sin nx = \sin 2nx$ ? Your sum should diverge almost everywhere...

Comment: I assume that it's $n \cos(nx) \sin(nx)$? Some parenthesis here wouldn't hurt.

Comment: @GabrielRomon Diverge to what? By symmetry neither $\pm\infty$ is a candidate, no?

Comment: Diverge does not only include converging to $\pm\infty$. For example, $1-1+1-1+\dots$ diverges. The above likely diverges just because the terms to not converge to zero.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I guess that's right although it feels weird to me to call a series with a limited partial sum 'divergent' (oscillating or just nonconvergent would seem better to me, but I don't make the terms). Given that, we have $x = \frac{\pi}{4}$ as divergent here.

Comment: Wikipedia: In mathematics, a divergent series is an infinite series that is not convergent, meaning that the infinite sequence of the partial sums of the series does not have a finite limit. Divergent does not mean what people thing it means.

Comment: @orlp you should get yourself a book on real analysis...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sum is not convergent everywhere nor is it bounded everywhere. As an counterexample, see $x = \frac{\pi}{4}$.

$$S(x) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} n\cos(nx)\sin(nx)$$
$$S(x) = \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} n\sin(2nx)$$
$$S(\frac{\pi}{4}) = \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} n\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}n)$$

Since $\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}n)$ alternates $0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 1, \dots$, the series does not converge. But the sum is also not bounded, look at the partial sums of the first $4k$ numbers:

$$\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{4k-1}n\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}n) = \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{j=0}^{k-1}\left ((4j+1) - (4j + 3)\right) = \sum\limits_{j=0}^{k-1}-1 = -k$$

So the partial sums also grow without bound.

Answer (score 1):

HINT $n\cos nx \sin nx = \frac{1}{2}n\sin 2nx$.

So you have $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n}{2}\sin 2nx$

Answer (score 0):

$n\cos x\sin x$, for most of $x$, $\cos x$ is not close to $0$, and so does $\sin x$, thus $n\cos(nx)\sin(nx)$ goes far.